# Why won't my program recognize a text file?

Tags: c#

Okay, so I have a text file called "Source.txt" and it contains code that needs to be read by my program.

I created Source.txt within a folder called "Resources" in my project, I created it, and currently its holding a couple resources.

In Form1, I'm trying to put the text in Source.txt into a string variable, like so:

```
string s = Properties.Resources.Source;
```

However, when I do that, it comes up with the error:

> does not contain a definition for 'Source'

How do I fix it?

Comment: In the properties dialog for the file, try change the BuildAction to EmbeddedResource.

Comment: I don't think that's where your compiler intends for you to place your source code. What product are you using? Visual Studio? Borland Builder? etc.

Comment: @Abe Miessler What do you mean by what's properties? @agent-j I tried it, and it didn't work.

Comment: Place the file with your source files and use the Project|Properties|Resources to add it to your project.

Comment: Jacob: 1. what do you mean by "contains code to be read"  Are you talking about source code or about just string resources that you are going to use for labels?

Comment: 2. You can't use ".txt" files as resource files.  .Net resource files are XML files with a very particular structure.  If you need a resource file, right click on your project name and click "properties" then go to the Resources tab.  Add the strings you need

Comment: Next review this for information on exactly what resources are.  I'm not sure you understand this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasham/RESOURCEFILES02132008080733AM/RESOURCEFILES.aspx

Comment: @Chris Lively So why there is option in resources to Add Text File? I think you can use txt files and assign them to String at least it works for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Chris Lively answered it in the comments:

> You can't use ".txt" files as resource files. .Net resource files are XML files with a very > particular structure. If you need a resource file, right click on your project name and          > click "properties" then go to the Resources tab. Add the strings you need

Here's what I did.

Step 1: Right click my project name, select Properties.

Step 2: Select the Resources tab in the properties window.

Step 3: Select the down arrow next to "Add Resource".

Step 4: Select "Add New Text File"

Step 5: Named the text file, added in what I wanted to the text file.

Its working great, thanks to all who contributed.